# Workflow Field update to Add 2 formula field doesn't calculate 2 fields Sum it simply shows 1st formula field's calculated value

Tags: formula, workflow, formula-field, field-update

[image][image]I have 2 formula fields A and B and then I'm updating C= A+B through workflow with criteria as Created and Every time its edited and formula as True.
Workflow i used due to formula field size limits. Now all this worked fine in sandbox but in production it gives result as C= A instead of C= A+B. It gives result as value of field A(which is formula field) instead of adding A+ B

Let me know what can be the issue or how to make it work.

Comment: Can you share the workflow rule and field update actions? That will help us to get to the correct solution.

Comment: I have updated question with snaps of Workflow rule criteria and field updates. Leadscore A and leadscore B are the formula fields.

Answer (score 0):

We'd need a bit more information to be sure, but one thing to keep in mind is that formula updates do not trigger workflow rules. That means that just because the value in A changes doesn't necessarily mean that your workflow will be triggered.

There is an idea [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrIGAA0) to change this but it doesnt look like it got added to the roadmap and likely won't change any time soon.